# Extending and displaying firebase user profile information always null

Tags: flutter, dart

Im having problems getting information from the firebase collection and display it to the user.

I get the information from the database and into a model.

```
  Future<AppUser> getUser(String uid) async {
    try {
      var userData = await _userCollectionReference.doc(uid).get();
      return AppUser.fromData(userData.data());
    } catch (e) {
      return e;
    }
  }
```

Using Provider in the screen

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final currentUser = Provider.of<AuthenticationService>(context).currentUser;

    return Scaffold(
```

however `currentUser` is always null which makes the app error

i have defined a MultiProvider in the main.dart

```
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<FirestoreService>(create: (_) => FirestoreService()),
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(create: (_) => AuthenticationService()),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) =>
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
        )
      ],
```

here is my appUser class

```
class AppUser {
  final String id;
  final String fullName;
  final String email;
  final String userRole;

  AppUser({this.id, this.fullName, this.email, this.userRole});

  AppUser.fromData(Map<String, dynamic> data)
      : id = data['id'],
        fullName = data['fullName'],
        email = data['email'],
        userRole = data['userRole'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'fullName': fullName,
      'email': email,
      'userRole': userRole,
    };
  }
}
```

and from my authenticationService

```
AppUser _currentUser;
  AppUser get currentUser => _currentUser;

Future signIn({String email, String password}) async {
    try {
      var authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      await _populateCurrentUser(authResult.user);

      return authResult != null;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
      }

     Future _populateCurrentUser(User user) async {
        if (_currentUser == null) {
          var userProfile = await _firestoreService.getUser(user.uid);
          _currentUser = userProfile;
        } else {
          return _currentUser;
        }
      }
```

Comment: So, where do you call `signIn`?

Comment: signin gets called from the login screen, the core above is from the home page. At which point the user is signed in

Comment: Well, I guess they are not signed in. Maybe you don't await the call? Hard to say without your code.